# Quarto server: shiny eval(xfun::parse_only(name)) : object 'html' not found

Tags: r, quarto

Adding `server: shiny` to my Quarto YAML gives the following error:

> Error in eval(xfun::parse_only(name)) : object 'html' not found
> Calls:  ... output_format_from_yaml_front_matter -> create_output_format_function -> eval -> eval
> Execution halted

Here is the Quarto document I am trying to run:

````
---
title: "Old Faithful"
format: html
server: shiny
---

```{r}
sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", 
            min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
plotOutput("distPlot")
```

```{r}
#| context: server
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  x <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
  bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
  hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
})
```
````

Here is my `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=C                             LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.7.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] cli_3.6.1        knitr_1.42       rlang_1.1.1      xfun_0.39        promises_1.2.0.1 jsonlite_1.8.4  
 [7] xtable_1.8-4     htmltools_0.5.5  httpuv_1.6.9     sass_0.4.5       rsconnect_0.8.29 rmarkdown_2.21  
[13] evaluate_0.20    jquerylib_0.1.4  ellipsis_0.3.2   fastmap_1.1.1    yaml_2.3.7       lifecycle_1.0.3 
[19] memoise_2.0.1    compiler_4.3.0   Rcpp_1.0.10      rstudioapi_0.14  later_1.3.1      digest_0.6.31   
[25] R6_2.5.1         magrittr_2.0.3   bslib_0.4.2      tools_4.3.0      mime_0.12        cachem_1.0.8
```

According to the [Quarto Shiny doc](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/shiny/) I need `rmarkdown` > 2.10, which I have (2.21).

Comment: To user shiny, you'll have to implement shiny logic. For example, see https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/shiny/execution.html

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes I had the same thought too (I mentioned this at the bottom of my post). I stripped away as much as possible to replicate and identify the issue in my post. I already tried the "Old Faithful" example and it returns the same error.

Comment: By shiny logic I meant R code, not the header. See how they wrote the example in the documentation I linked.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Right, what I am saying is I have run that exact example and still receive this error. I copied and pasted it directly from the link into a fresh R session and Quarto document.

Comment: Perhaps add that attempt into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I followed [the fix posted on Github here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12546#issuecomment-1540399151), copied below:

> Install `usethis` package in RStudio
>
> Run `usethis::edit_r_environ()` in RStudio Console -- .Renviron file is opened
>
> Add QUARTO_R="<absolute/path/to/R/bin>" to the file (eg. QUARTO_R="C:\R\R-4.2.2\bin") and save
>
> Restart R Session

After the restart, the (unchanged) document renders successfully.